# qt creator unwanted disassembly

Tags: qt, debugging, disassembly

I had this very annoying problem that while debugging, suddenly it started to show the disassembled code rather than the C++ code, via google I found several with the same problem, and a suggested weird solution [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/613698/How-to-enable-non-disassembler-debug-in-QT-Creator) which I'm not sure how to interpret. I tried things similar to that post and found a solution:

1. Shut down and restart QT Creator
2. In left-hand tab "Projects", untick then re-tick "Shadow build"

Seems like voodoo right? But I noticed that step 1 clears all breakpoints, and step 2 temporarily changes some paths after which it says "evaluating" for a second in the lower right corner. So perhaps it's not as weird as it sounds, apparently a few things are cleared during this process.

I don't think I'm supposed to write answers to my own problems here but I thought it would be a waste not to post this solution to this very annoying problem that apparently more than I have encountered. The next guy hopefully finds my post.

I cant post links to others with similar problems since I need a higher reputation then.. :-/

Comment: It's legit to post answers to your own question. But please ask the question in the main topic and answer it after that.

Comment: You rescued my bacon, buddy. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It probably helps if you uncheck options to break debugging on Thread creation and Thread exit if you have these options checked for the Debugger. These options will certainly pop the disassembler view up when you start debugging even if you haven't set any Breakpoints in your code. You find these options in menu Tools/Debugger/CDB. If you want to break on C++ exceptions leave that option checked, otherwise uncheck that too.